# Create column-based dataframe from two RDDs in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I have two RDDs. Each of them is a key-value pair:

rdd1:

```
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
```

rdd2:

```
('a', 3)
('c', 2)
```

I want to combine them in a pyspark sql dataframe such that:

```
        a   b   c
rdd1    1   2   0
rdd2    3   0   2
```

Is there a way to do so? Or do I need to change the way I create my rdd1 and rdd2?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share more info, how you are creating rdd's?  ref this link, might give some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348236/convert-row-values-into-columns-with-its-value-from-another-column-in-spark-scal

Comment: I create the rdds by counting the word frequency in a document. Each RDD is one document